# Get the name of the parent field in the child function

Tags: javascript

I need to get the name of the parent element (CentralS) in the child function, how can this be done?
.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

[image]

```
 const roles = {
 CentralS: {
      'harvester': {
        'quantity': 3,
        'currentQuantity': _.sum(Game.creeps, (c) => {

          if (c.memory.role === 'harvester') {
            // console.log(c.memory.spawnName)
            console.log(Object.keys(this))
            console.log(this)

          }
          return c.memory.role === 'harvester';
        }),
        'strength': [WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE]
      }
    },
    CentralS1: {
      'harvester': {
        'quantity': 3,
        'currentQuantity': _.sum(Game.creeps, (c) => {

          if (c.memory.role === 'harvester') {
            // console.log(c.memory.spawnName)
            console.log(Object.keys(this))
            console.log(this)

          }
          return c.memory.role === 'harvester';
        }),
        'strength': [WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE]
      }
    },
    CentralS2: {
      'harvester': {
        'quantity': 3,
        'currentQuantity': _.sum(Game.creeps, (c) => {

          if (c.memory.role === 'harvester') {
            // console.log(c.memory.spawnName)
            console.log(Object.keys(this))
            console.log(this)

          }
          return c.memory.role === 'harvester';
        }),
        'strength': [WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE]
      }
    }
  }
```

**my solution**

```
const roles = {
    CentralS: {
      'harvester': {
        'quantity': 3,
        'strength': [WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE]
      }
   }
}
for (const spawnName in roles) {
    for (const roleName in roles[spawnName]) {
      if (roles[spawnName].hasOwnProperty(roleName)) {
        roles[spawnName][roleName].currentQuantity = _.sum(Game.creeps, (c) => {
console.log(spawnName) // CentralS
          return c.memory.role === roleName && c.memory.spawnName === spawnName;
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's not possible. Objects don't have any links back to the objects that contain references to them.

Comment: Objects don't have any "parent" property, unless you attach such a property manually.

Comment: Then I have to write CentralS, CentralS1, CentralS2 in every function in this object manually ? Can't I somehow get the name of this generic object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to define `currentQuantity` property outside the body of that object, like this:

```
const roles = {
 CentralS: {
    'harvester': {
      'quantity': 3,
      'strength': [WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE]
    }
  }
};

roles.CentralS.harvester.currentQuantity = _.sum(Game.creeps, (c) => {
  if (c.memory.role === 'harvester') {
    // console.log(c.memory.spawnName)
    console.log(Object.keys(this))
    console.log(this)

    console.log(roles.CentralS);    
  }
  return c.memory.role === 'harvester';
});
```

Comment: Yes, good idea, I used cycle and get what i want for (const spawnName in roles) {
    for (const roleName in roles[spawnName]) {

      roles[spawnName].roleName.currentQuantity = _.sum(Game.creeps, (c) => {
        console.log(spawnName) // CentralS
        return c.memory.role === roleName;
      })
    }
  }